# problems resetting mysql root password

Tags: mysql, password, 19.10, reset

I have issues resetting the root password for my mysql server on Ubuntu 19.10:
I followed the instructions on https://websiteforstudents.com/resetting-mysql-root-password-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-and-18-04-lts/ and everything goes like the instructions say until I get to the step where I'm supposed to login with `sudo mysql -u root`. I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I checked my bind-addresses in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`. 
I have three, they are  set to:

```
127.0.0.1, 
10.0.2.15 (my local ethernet iface) and 
0.0.0.0
```

so i don't know why it doesn't let me connect, any hints? I have set 
`sudo ufw enable` & `sudo ufw allow mysql` - even after `sudo ufw disablle` it won't let me connect!

Comment: I'm curious if you fixed this in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, I would say that you are not trying to connect to what you think you are. Try adding the  `--host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306` to explicitly set the host/port you are trying to connect to.

Also, increase verbosity with  `-vvv`

Check that mysqld is actually listening with

```
sudo ss -nlpt | grep -i mysqld
```

Permit all traffic on port 3306:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```